# PHP multiple explode key value array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Hey guys i've got a string which looks like this:

```
b:Blue | y:Yellow | r:Red
```

and want to convert this string into an array with key value.

```
array(
  'b' => 'Blue',
  'y' => 'Yellow',
  'r' => 'Red'
);
```

I'm quite familiar with php except for explode stuff…

Comment: Try something please, hints: `explode()` or `preg_split()` and you need `array_combine()`.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: "I'm quite familiar with php except for" Good thing the community has created a very nice manual just for these type of situations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about RTFM

Comment: try splitting by '|' first.. then split again with ':' finally create an array based on those values.. good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to split things, match it instead:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w):(\w+)/', 'b:Blue | y:Yellow | r:Red', $matches);
print_r(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

It matches an alphanumeric character, followed by a colon and then more alphanumeric characters; both parts are captured in memory groups. Finally, the first memory groups are combined with the second memory groups.

A more hacked approach is this:

```
parse_str(strtr('b:Blue | y:Yellow | r:Red', ':|', '=&'), $arr);
print_r(array_map('trim', $arr));
```

It turns the string into something that looks like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then parses it with [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str). Afterwards, you need to trim any trailing and leading spaces from the values though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "b:Blue | y:Yellow | r:Red";
//split string at ' | '
$data = explode(" | ", $string);
$resultArray = array();
//loop through split result
foreach($data as $row) {
    //split again at ':'
    $result = explode(":", $row);
    //add key / value pair to result array
    $resultArray[$result[0]] = $result[1];
}
//print result array
print_r($resultArray);
```

Comment: If you ever write code (on SO), please add some comments.

Comment: @HamZa: Added some comments. But for someone who is familiar with php this shouldn't be a problem at all :)

Comment: that's undoubtedly not true since this could be solved by just searching and reading the manual, and if it's true he must be lazy :)

Comment: @HamZa Back in high school (Would be college in the US I think) my teacher always said that well written code should not need comments or at least only few. But you make a good point.

Comment: @HamZa You have a point here :D Also i should not forget that there could be others reading this thread with not as much "experience" as the OP.

Comment: @RichardA I totally agree, don't get me wrong. I won't ever comment this simple code in realworld lol. It's just that if you answer on SO, it's best to add some comments so that the OP can understand what's going on and hopefully get the "concept" and not the "code".

Comment: @HamZa Or atleast a single line just for clarification.

Comment: Correct, anyways I appreciate the efforts so voted up your answers you two guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$str = "b:Blue | y:Yellow | r:Red";

// Split on ' | ', creating an array of the 3 colors 
$split = explode(' | ', $str);

$colors = array();

foreach($split as $spl)
{
    // For each color now found, split on ':' to seperate the colors.
    $split2 = explode(':', $spl);

    // Add to the colors array, using the letter as the index. 
    // (r:Red becomes 'r' => 'red')
    $colors[$split2[0]] = $split2[1];
}

print_r($colors);

/*
Array
(
    [b] => Blue
    [y] => Yellow
    [r] => Red
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

explode first with **|** and after **:**

```
// I got the from php.net
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
    array_shift($delimiters);
    if($delimiters != NULL) {
        foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
             $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
        }
    }
    return  $ary;
}
$string = "b:Blue | y:Yellow | r:Red"; // Your string

$delimiters = array(" | ", ":"); // | important that it is first
$matches = multiexplode($delimiters, $string);

/*
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => string 'Blue' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'y' (length=1)
      1 => string 'Yellow' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'r' (length=1)
      1 => string 'Red' (length=3)
*/
```